# Swift 5.5, when to use `Task.suspend` in custom async implementation?

Tags: swift, async-await, swift5

The new Async/Await syntax looks great! but I wonder how to implement my own asynchronous implementation.

I've stumbled upon this API:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3862702-suspend (overview in `yield`)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/3814840-yield (renamed to `suspend`)

This API allows me to suspend a task manually whenever I choose. The problem is, I'm am not sure how SHOULD I do it, in order to benefit from concurrency AND not avoid bad practices.

In other word, I don't know the best practices of `Task.suspend()`

for example:

```swift
func example() async {
    for i in 0..<100 {
        print("example", i)
        await Task.suspend() // <-- is this OK?
    }
}
```

Some specific questions:

- how often should one call on `suspend`?
- should `suspend` be called before an intensive operation, or after? (for example: IO, Crypto, etc...)
- should there be a maximum amount of calls to `suspend`?
- what is the "price" of calling `suspend` intensively?
- when should one NOT call `suspend`?
- are there any other ways to implement this kind of concurrency (async/await style, not GCD)

**Real life example**, I'm implementing a function that encrypts the content of a big file, since it is an IO+Crypto intensive task it should be async, I wonder how to use `Task.suspend` (or any other async/await tools) to make it asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `Task.suspend()` will suspend the current task for a few milliseconds in order to give some time to any tasks that might be waiting, which is particularly important if you’re doing intensive work in a loop and all your tasks use the same priority. Otherwise your heavy task can stop all asynchronous code in your app. For instance:

```swift
func f() async {
    for _ in 0...10 {
        var arr = (1...10000).map {_ in arc4random()}
        arr.sort()
    }
    print("f")
}

func z() async {
    print("z")
}

// Run in parallel

Task {
    await f()
}

Task {
    await z()
}
```

Outputs:

```sh
f
z
```

As you can see `z()` waits for `f()` because it does long-running operation of sorting a large array many times. To fix this you can add `Task.suspend()` in your loop:

```swift
func f() async {
    for _ in 0...10 {
        var arr = (1...10000).map {_ in arc4random()}
        arr.sort()

        await Task.suspend() // Voluntarily suspend itself 
    }
    print("f")
}
```

Outputs:

```sh
z
f
```

`async/await` works on its own cooperative concurrent queues and if you don't want to do suspending consider moving your task to non-default priority(queue) e.g. `Task(priority: .background)` or run your heavy task on your separate queue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you also reply on the other questions I've asked later on in the post?
Moreover, I would like your opinion on my "real life" example with encrypting a large file